# Load ROS projects inside Eclipse

Tags: catkin-make, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I am trying quite a reasonable time to load a ros package as a project in Eclipse. Of course I am following the steps of section **2.2 Catkin-y approach** from the tutorial [IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Reusing_your_shell.27s_environment) but It is not working. I also checked the [Catkin and eclipse](http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/) answer. All the times that I tried to import a package as a Eclipse project I got **No projects are found to import** as show in the following screeshot:
[image: image description]

I will appreciate any king of help or tip like: Should I reinstall eclipse, should I create a new catkin workspace, ...

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227600/load-ros-projects-inside-eclipse/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many things that you might be missing:

- When doing catkin_make make sure that you have done `catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"` otherwise the Eclipse configuration files are not going to be there ( I assume this is OK). To validate this, in your `build/` folder there should be two files: `.cproject` and `.project`.
- I assume you are following the [IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Reusing_your_shell.27s_environment) tutorial exactly as they say (regarding how Eclipse should be installed). Specially, regarding how you launch Eclipse. In my case, I have a `EclipseROS.desktop` file in`~/.local/share/applications/` that looks as follows:

> 

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 4
Type=Application
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=1 bash -i -c "/opt/eclipse/eclipse"
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=EclipseROS
Name[en_US]=EclipseROS
```

And my `.bashrc` constains `source` ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

- Finally, simply browse in your `build/` folder, do not go down to the package folder, because is in build where the Eclipse configuration files `.cproject` and `.project` are generated (at least for `catkin_make`, for `catkin tools` a couple of files is generated for every package).

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-02-26**:
Thanks, everything was corrected but instead of browse in the **build/** folder I was browsing in the packge folders. Naive mistake.